# XElement Linq query to count number of decendant elements that match attribute value

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

I'm trying to find the number of  child elements of  where the 'index' attribute matches '2'. I'm expecting an integer value of 2.

My code compiles but generates an error at runtime.

My xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset>
  <bootfilescomponents>
    <bootfiles index="1">
      <name>Boot Files v2.0</name>
      <file path="File1"></file>
    </bootfiles>
    <bootfiles index="2">
      <name>Boot Files v1.0</name>
      <file path="File1"></file>
      <file path="File2"></file>
    </bootfiles>
    <bootfiles index="3">
      <name>Boot Files v1.3</name>
      <file path="File1"></file>
      <file path="File2"></file>
      <file path="File3"></file>
    </bootfiles>
  </bootfilescomponents>
</dataset>
```

And here's the code.

```
xe = XElement.Load("dataset.xml")
Dim NumberOfMatches As Integer = xe.Descendants("bootfiles").Elements("file").Count(Function(x) x.Attribute("index").Value = "2")
```

Can anyone help me understand where I've gone wrong?

edit:  A solution using LINQ

```
    Dim ct As Integer = 0
    Dim nm As String = "file"
    ct = (From el In xe.Descendants(nm)
            Where el.Parent.Name.LocalName = "bootfiles" AndAlso
            el.Parent.@index = "2"
            Select el).Count
```

Comment: please always post the complete error message

Comment: You are applying the index condition to "file" elements which do not have an index attribute. Apply it to the boot files: `xe.Descendants("bootfiles").Where(Function(bootFile) bootFile.Attribute("index").Value = "2").Elements("file").Count()`

Comment: 'I'm trying to find the number of child (file?) elements of where the 'index' attribute matches '2'. I'm expecting an integer value of 2.

        Dim ct As Integer = 0

        ct = (From el In xe...<file>
                Where el.Parent.Name.LocalName = "bootfiles" AndAlso el.Parent.@index = "2"
                Select el).Count

Comment: Thank you @OlivierJacot-Descombes, that makes perfect sense! Though I'm still seeing an issue with the 'Function' part of the code which is throwing a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Hi @dbasnett, your code snippet works perfectly, thank you! I wish I understood why my original code was throwing an error but I'm so happy I can get on with this project now. Thank you everyone!

Comment: It is working for me with the XML example from above. If e.g. a bootfile is missing the index attribute, then `bootFile.Attribute("index").Value` will throw the Null Ref Exception. Try `bootFile.Attribute("index")?.Value`. Your original code tried to get the index attribute from **file** elements (because the condition was after `.Elements("file")`) instead of from **bootFile** elements. Therefore the Attribute was Nothing and trying to get `.Value` from Nothing throws the exception.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, great explanation, thank you. If I add the '?' as you showed then the compiler reports that the " '?' cannot be used here".

Comment: It works for me. The [Null-Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) has been introduced in Visual Basic 2015. It's `?.`, not `?`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thank you for confirming that. It looks like I'm facing a compiler issue now then. This does make me wonder why it's throwing the error when each ```<bootfiles>``` has the "index" attribute then?

Comment: `Dim NumberOfMatches As Integer = xe.Descendants("bootfiles").Where(Function(bootFile) bootFile.Attribute("index").Value = "2").Elements("file").Count()` works perfectly for me. Did you remove the Function from `Count`?

Comment: I did remove the function from ```Count```. Though I've updated my compiler and now the nullable value works as expected. So I think that clears everything up. Thank you @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I've used your code snippet as it's a little more flexible than using XML literals, and thank you @dbasnett for your snippet too as this is also a valid solution!

Comment: @Darryl - '... as it's a little more flexible than using XML literals'  How so?

Comment: @dbasnett - the query is part of a function used many times in my code, while my example references an XML element ```"File"``` I need to change this reference using a variable and I could not find a way of doing this using XML literals. Of course, I may be wrong and I'm happy to be corrected. Either way, your code is very clever and I have saved a copy of it for future reference, so please accept my thanks for your help and brilliant example!

Comment: @Darryl - I added a string variable, nm, before the ct and changed the first line of the LINQ to From el In xe.Descendants(nm).